# OptimisticLockException in inner transaction ruins outer transaction

Tags: hibernate, spring, transactions

I have the following code `(OLE = OptimisticLockException)`...

```
public void outer() {

  try {
    middle()
  } catch (OLE) {
    updateEntities();
    outer();
  }
}

@Transactional
public void middle() {
  try {
    inner()
  } catch (OLE) {
    updateEntities();
    middle();
}

@Transactional
public void inner() {
  //Do DB operation
}
```

`inner()` is called by other non-transactional methods which is why both `middle()` and `inner()` are transactional.  As you can see, I deal with OLEs by updating the entities and retrying the operation.

The problem I'm having is that when I designed things this way I was assuming that the only time one could get an OLE was when a transaction closed.  This is apparently not the case as the call to `inner()` is throwing an OLE even when the stack is `outer()->middle()->inner()`.

Now, `middle()` is properly handling the OLE and the retry succeeds but when it comes time to close the transaction it has been marked `rollbackOnly` by Spring.  When the `middle()` method call finally returns the closing aspect throws an exception because it can't commit a transaction marked `rollbackOnly`.

I'm uncertain what to do here.  I can't clear the `rollbackOnly` state.  I don't want to force create a transaction on every call to inner because that kills my performance.  Am I missing something or can anyone see a way I can structure this differently?

EDIT: To clarify what I'm asking, let me explain my main question.  Is it possible to catch and handle OLE if you are inside of an @Transactional method?

FYI: The transaction manager is a JpaTransactionManager and the JPA provider is Hibernate.

Comment: Not enough information or you're not clearly describing the problem. Is there are recursive call in outer() btw?

Comment: I added a clarification at the end which states my exact question.  outer() recursively calls itself and so does middle().  inner() does not recursively call itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after trying for a while, I guess the answer is no.  Anytime you catch an OLE you have to make sure that you start a new transaction.  I went ahead and restructured my code so that middle didn't have to catch the OLE.